# CasperJS waitForSelector doesn't add "then" to step array

Tags: javascript, promise, phantomjs, casperjs

This is how my code looks like:

```
var firstFrameLoadingTime = 3000;

firstFrameLoadingWaiter(function() {
    casper.echo("callback");
});

function firstFrameLoadingWaiter(callback) {
    casper.waitForSelector('div',
        function suc() {
            casper.echo('success!');
        },
        function timeout() {        
                casper.echo('failure!');
        },
        firstFrameLoadingTime);
}
```

The problem is that `suc` function is never called. I mean it's not added to the array of CasperJS steps.

This is a part of the log:

```
[18] => [info] [phantom] Step _step 5/5 https://... (HTTP 200)
[19] => [info] [phantom] Step _step 5/5: done in 3392ms.
[20] => [info] [phantom] waitFor() finished in 40ms.
[21] => [info] [phantom] Done 5 steps in 3451ms
```

If selector isn't found on a page before timeout comes script works like a charm.

**UPD**. As it turned out the problem was in `do_while` and `waitFor` incompatibility.

Comment: Could you please post all your code out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time of research I found out that the problem was in [do_while](https://github.com/yotsumoto/casperjs-goto) modification of `step.then` function. `do_while` was incompatible with the `waitFor` function.

The workaround ([pull request](https://github.com/yotsumoto/casperjs-goto/pull/4)) is simple though not the clearest.
I've just named the function in a special way and added a small check:

```
var isWaitSuccessFun = step.name.indexOf('successThen') != -1;
if( isWaitSuccessFun || !this.steps[this.current].executed ) {
```

To make your `waitFor` work just ensure the success function name contains `successThen` as in example:

```
casper.waitFor(
    function check(){
        // check if page is ready
    },
    function successThen(){
        // execute after page is ready
    },
    function(){
        // time out happened before page got ready
    },
    timeOutTime
);
```

This also makes `waitForSelector` work as well as other similar functions based on `waitFor`.

The full code is available in my [forked repository](https://github.com/MrQwert/casperjs-goto).